# Contact form doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I have a simple contact form on `contact.php`, but submitting it there is no any data into corresponding php file `(mail.php)`.

form inside contact.php

```
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your name">
<br><br>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your mail">
<br><br>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
</form>
```

js inside contact.php

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
$.post("mail.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
$('#success').html(response);
});
return false;
});
```

mail.php

```
   print_r( $_POST );
    if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
    die("All fields must be filled !");
    }
```

result:
`Array ( ) All fields must be filled !`

Comment: Which data gets sent to the server? Use Fiddler or your favorite browser debugging tool's network tab to determine this

Comment: @Kippie, I checked with firebug. `Post` tab is empty, `Response` tab has response content as the result in my post, i.e. `Array ( ) All fields must be filled !`

Comment: @SunSky Are your input fields properly named? I.e. `<input type="text" name="name">` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yes, I checked twice

Comment: Can you try `die('<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>');` and then use your Network Tab to see what is going to your script?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I placed my form code into the post. Please check.

Comment: @SunSky I think this is the problem `<input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" />` try changing it to `<input type="submit" value=" SEND " id="submit" />`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, Should I place your code instead this line: `die("All fields must be filled !");` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I tried. The same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work for me.

This is a.html file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                $.post("x.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
                    $('#success').html(response);
                });

            });  
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your name">
            <br><br>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your mail">
            <br><br>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
        </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is x.php file

```
    <?php
       print_r( $_POST );
        if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
        die("All fields must be filled !");
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Dalim, your code works. Thanks. Could you check, please what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Same answer with Jenson M John's . You should use $(function(){ \\ jquery codes ... }) pattern

Answer (score 2):

Working Example:

```
    <html>
        <head>
           <title>Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        div { color:blue; margin:3px; cursor:pointer; }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(e){
        $.post("mail.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
        });
        return false;
        });  
        }); 
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="success"></div>
            <form name="contact" id="contact" method="post">
            <?php
              for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
              {?>
              Text Box <?php echo $i; ?>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="in<?php echo $i; ?>"/><br/><br/>
              <?php
              }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
    print_r( $_POST );
    if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
    die("All fields must be filled !");
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: You should have included your js code within $(document).ready(function(){ or $(function(){

Answer (score -1):

Try it, will prevent your form to submit naturally:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

One other change you may try is:

```
$("#contact").serializeArray()
```